# plot and draw curves in python matplotlib without ignoring first and last Nan values from the graph figure

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have csv format file like the below table

| depth | x1 | x2 | x3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 15 | Nan | Nan |
| 1001 | 10 | Nan | Nan |
| 1002 | 5 | Nan | Nan |
| 1003 | 8 | 10 | Nan |
| 1004 | 12 | 11.11111111 | Nan |
| 1010 | 13 | 17.77777778 | 14.16666667 |
| 1011 | 14 | 18.88888889 | 15 |
| 1012 | 15 | 20 | 15.71428571 |
| 1013 | 16 | 20.55555556 | 16.42857143 |
| 1014 | 17 | 21.11111111 | 17.14285714 |
| 1017 | 20 | 22.77777778 | 19.28571429 |
| 1018 | 21 | 23.33333333 | 20 |
| 1019 | 22 | 23.88888889 | 20.83333333 |
| 1024 | 27 | 17.5 | 25 |
| 1025 | 28 | 15 | 25 |
| 1026 | 25 | Nan | Nan |
| 1027 | 26 | Nan | Nan |
| 1028 | 7 | Nan | Nan |

I want to plot x1, x2, x3 columns versus depth columns but sometimes these columns contain Nan values at start and end of columns, I want to plot whole curves points without ignoring the first and last Nan values

the below code is my attempt to plot curves but the plot always start and end at first and last valid values and ignores the first and last Nan values

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
df = pd.read_csv("result.csv")
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 12), dpi=100, tight_layout=True)
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(nrows=1, ncols=5, wspace=0)
fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 1])
plt.plot(df['x1'],df["depth"], linewidth=2, color='black', marker="o", markersize=3)
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
fig.add_subplot(gs[0,2 ])
plt.plot(df["x2"],df["depth"], linewidth =2, color='black', marker="o", markersize=3)
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
fig.add_subplot(gs[0,3])
plt.plot(df["x3"],df["depth"], linewidth =2, color='black', marker="o", markersize=3)
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.show()
```

the current reult

[image]

the desired result in the below image where all curves y axis start from same  depth point
[image]

Comment: What do you expect? [mre]

Comment: It would be helpful to include an image of the current graph and a mockup of the expected result

Comment: I pasted the current result from python viewr while the  desired one is edited in photoshop

Answer (score 1):

You need to [share the y axis with the other y axis](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.sharey.html):

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(15, 12), dpi=100, tight_layout=True, gridspec_kw={'wspace': 0})
axs[0].plot(df.x1, df.depth, '-ok', lw=2, ms=3)
axs[1].plot(df.x2, df.depth, '-ok', lw=2, ms=3)
axs[1].sharey(axs[0])
axs[2].plot(df.x3, df.depth, '-ok', lw=2, ms=3)
axs[2].sharey(axs[0])
```

[image]